# What gender(s) are political parties?

Tags: genre, noms-propres, abréviations, politique

For example the parties: LR PS  FN

And is it the same gender for all parties? What about "UDI" can you use l'UDI ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gender of the underlying words is kept, i.e. Le PS (Le parti socialiste), Le FN (le front national). Most are masculine, an exception is LS (La ligue du sud).

Note that no article is prepended when one is already present like LR (Les républicains), or in some other cases like EELV (Europe Écologie Les Verts), DLF (Debout la France) or LO (Lutte ouvrière).

Comment: And sorry to confirm you use the il/elle forme for verbs? Le FN va...

Comment: Yes, that would be le "FN va...", "l'UDI va..." There is an issue with LR as one would probably say "LR a gagné x régions" but "Les Républicains ont gagné x régions."